# How to unlock screen from script in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: linux, kde, screensaver

I use pam_usb and want to lock/unlock computer when USB stick is removed/inserted. For locking I use `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock` and it works perfectly. For unlocking I've tried a series of commands I've found (most of them are aggregated [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12495/unlock-your-kde4-session-remotely-for-boxes-locked-by-kde-lock-utility)), but they don't work. Specifically, if we exclude those with KDE 4 syntax, they fall into 2 categories: those using `qdbus (relevant path here, several variations exists) /MainApplication quit` which hang my Xorg completely, and those using `killall` against screenlocker process, but the process just restarts instantly after that!

So, my question is: how to unlock KDE5 screen locked with its standard locker programmatically?

Comment: I want to do the same thing but using [BlueProximity](http://blueproximity.sourceforge.net) {at 1.2.5 at present on my system - Debian Old-stable (Wheezy)} - the above, written more fully as `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock` does activate the screensaver in "locked" mode {you can replace the last fragment with `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SetActive` `true` to put up the saver without a lock} and in either case you may get the screen back with that latter with `false` - but the monitor (not the whole screen as I have two monitor in one virtual...

Comment: ... screen) is unresponsive to keystrokes or mouse clicks - the other monitor behaves normally and so do windows on the "inactive" once I have <alt>-<tab>bed to them from the working window and then used <alt><F3> (window operations) to move them with the arrow keys to the working window.  I use KDE and have extra widgets showing on the saver screen (a clock and a CPUs activity monitor - for those long build jobs) and they and the "unlock/switch user" widget also remain. Normality is restored by entering the password in the dialog from the "unlock".  I, too, need a command to unlock properly.

Comment: *after a bit of experimenting* - Ah, I'm on KDE4 not 5 so my: `kill \`ps ax | grep "kscreenlocker" | grep -v grep | cut -d" " -f 1\`` is not going to be much help to you though it works in my particular case...

Comment: Thank you for sharing an experience! But, unfortunately, `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SetActive false` doesn't unlock screen on my Arch Linux with KDE PLasma 5.6.1

Comment: It doesn't for me either! That only kills the screeen saver if it has been activated with the `... org.freedesktop.SetActive true` (i.e. in "saver" mode) rather than via `... org.freedesktop.Lock` (i.e. in "lock" mode). That is why I had to resort to using `kill` on any `kscreenlocker` processes running under **my** UID. kscreenlocker is what runs the selected screensaver(s) at least in my setup, however *YMMV*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not really my answer, but it might be useful to someone else too.
It comes from https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=130691#p350000 and it works on latest archlinux with kde 5.7

```
loginctl lock-session
loginctl unlock-session
```

Comment: How can I do this WITHOUT systemd, just dbus?

Comment: @Luke-Jr This works for me: `qdbus --system org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1/session/self org.freedesktop.login1.Session.Lock` (and `Unlock` similarly) - You can probably do the same with `dbus-send`, but I'm not familiar with that tool. As for systems that do not have systemd, there will still be a logind implementation because most desktop environments require logind these days.

Comment: Service 'org.freedesktop.login1' does not exist.

logind is just part of systemd as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: (and looking at alternative logind implementations, none of them look like something I'd want to install)

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Neither`loginctl` nor `qdbus` are unlocking my screen.  killing `kscreenlocker_greet` also isn't working (it just respawns).  any other options?

Comment: If the DBus API is not working, I'd suggest that you file a bug report at https://bugs.kde.org

Comment: you need to also specify the session id, see this answer instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/611611/378854

Answer (score 2):

*The screen locker is broken and unlocking is not possible anymore. In order to unlock switch to a virtual terminal (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), log in and execute the command:
loginctl unlock-sessions
Afterwards switch back to the running session (Ctrl+Alt+F7).*

The above message appears sometimes on my laptop running Gentoo Stable with Plasma 5, OpenRC and ConsoleKit. The following script I launch from TTY1 successfully unlocks the X11 session on TTY7:

```
fitzcarraldo@clevow230ss ~ $ cat unlockKDEsession.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Screen locker broken in KDE with ConsoleKit
# See https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1046566.html
# and https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1054134.html

# Find which session is locked
session=Session$(ck-list-sessions | grep -B10 "x11-display = ':0" | grep -o -P '(?<=Session).*(?=:)')

# Create Bash script to unlock session
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /unlock.sh
echo "su -c 'dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=\"org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit\" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/$session org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.Unlock'" >> /unlock.sh
chmod +x /unlock.sh

# Run Bash script in another TTY
openvt -s -w /unlock.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

On modern KDE Plasma the command is apparently:

```
qdbus --system org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/$session Unlock
```

The session name can be obtained from

```
qdbus --literal --system org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessions | sed 's/^.*\(Session[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Beware, as there can be multiple sessions!
There are several `GetSession*` functions for varying use cases though.

The problem is, that **all these functions** of course **require root!**

I don’t know how how `loginctl` would circumvent this, but it suggests it is possible. Otherwise maybe you can [use `sudo` and allow a script that does this to be run without entering a password](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Allow_users_to_shutdown#Using_sudo).

Comment: Evi1M4chine: please take a look at my question.

Comment: @e-pirate: I did re-check your question, and it seems my solution fits it perfectly. Please look at my answer. Did I miss something?

Comment: After some googling I found this `/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.LockSessions` to work perfectly well. But thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Evi1M4chine's recipe for quite a while to lock sessions on lid close (as a part of sophisticated script) like this:

```
for SESSION in $(qdbus --literal --system org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessions | sed 's/^.*\(Session[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'); do
  dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/$SESSION org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.Lock
done
```

But modern KDE5/Plasma dropped `org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit` rendering this approach non working. I spent some time trying to figure out how to adopt this to actual dbus -with no luck. Any ideas how to make this work on modern KDE5/Plasma?